# exception when running incoming RPC call on EclipseLink

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, rpc

I'm writing a project with Eclipse using EclipseLink ,hsqldb and GWT . When I try a do a RPC I always get stuck on this exception :

> SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
>   com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void it.myProject.client.service.EmployeeService.createEmployee()' threw an unexpected exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for >"myDB" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl

This is my main file **myProject.java** where I execute the RPC:

```
public class MyProject implements EntryPoint {  

 private final EmployeeServiceAsync aService = (EmployeeServiceAsync)             GWT.create(EmployeeService.class);

   @Override
   public void onModuleLoad() {

     aService.createEmployee(new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            Window.alert("Creation Employees failed!");
        }
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void result) {
            Window.alert("Creation success!");
        }
    });
```

I've specified the name of my Database and the provider in **persistence.xml** :

```
 <persistence-unit name="myDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> 
 <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

In my **build path** I've put: eclipselink.jar ; gwt-servlet.jar ; hsqldb.jar ; javax.persistence_2.0.4.jar ; persistence-api-sources-2.0.jar ; smartgwt.jar

Please give me some advice to resolve this exception...I'm blocked since a week!!Feel free to ask for other codes if you need!

Comment: noone have an idea or a question for me?

Comment: really no responces??